# Cannot reference global class instance in SSRS report Header/Footer?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, rdl

I have a report which uses a custom assembly for purposes of localization/globalization.

I am creating my translation object (I'll call it "dictionary") and initializing a Dictionary property of this object in the custom code OnInit() override.

Everything works fine in report body, but when I try to reference the object I describe above in either the Report Header or Report Footer- it is not accessible (object ref is not set to instance of obj error..).

Can anyone either tell me why this is or how I might be able to workaround it? I really don't want to have to re-initialize this localization object separately for the Header and Footer. I was under the impression custom code class instances were accessible anywhere within the report definition.

Thanks in advance for any light anyone can shed on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of your implementation, but the recommendation is to use static methods rather than instances.  Understood that this is not always the best case for each design, but in your case, it sounds like you could use a static method and then in that case, when called from your header and footer, the custom assembly static method will initialize all data.  It will be easier that putting the implementation or instance creation in the RDL.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to just be by design. A custom class instance is not accessible to the Report Header or Footer. My solution was to simply add a check to the custom code function which the report expressions call (psuedo-code):

If IsNothing(myCustObj)
{
  ///initialize myCustObj
}

That seems to be the best workaround.